# C++ Find all combinations of elements in multiple arrays in Breadth-first search manner

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, combinations, permutation

I've got multiple arrays and want to find the permutations of all the elements in these arrays. Each element also carries a weight, and these arrays are sorted decreasing by weight. I've got an array with weight that mimics the arrays with he values themselves. I want my search to find permutations with the greatest weight to the lowest weight.

However, each element in an array has a weight associated with it so I want to run my search with those with the highest weight first.

Example:

```
arr0 = [A, B, C, D]  
arr0_weight = [11, 7, 4, 3]  
arr1 = [W, X, Y]  
arr1_weight = [10, 9, 4]
```

Thus, the ideal output would be:

```
AW (11+10=21)  
AX (11+9=20)  
BW (7+10=17)  
BX (7+9=16)  
AY (11+4=15)  
...
```

If I did just a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr0)/4; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(arr1)/4; j++) {
    cout << arr0[i] << arr1[j] << endl; }}
```

I would get:

```
AW (11+10=21)   
AX (11+9=20)  
AY (11+4=15)  
BW (7+10=17)  
BX (7+9=16)  
BZ (7+4=11)
```

Which isn't what I want because 17 > 15 and 16 > 15.

Also, what's a good way to do this for n arrays? If I don't know how many arrays I will have, and their size might not all be the same?

I've looked into putting the values into vectors but I can't find a way to do what I want (a sorted Cartesian product). Any help? Pseudo-code is fine if you don't have time - I'm just really stuck.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about algorithm, not C++.

You want to sort all tuples in Cartesian product from heaviest to lightest.

Easiest way is to find all tuples and sort them by their weight.

If you need sequential access, your should do following. Since weight of tuple is sum of weights of its elements, I think, greediness is optimal here. Let's move to arbitrary number of arrays of arbitrary dimensions. Create set of indices. Initially, it's contains zeros. First tuple that it represents is obviously heaviest. Find one of indices to increment: choose index that loses least weight, that has least difference with next element. Don't forget to keep track of exhausted arrays. When all vectors are exhausted, you're done.

To implement it in C++, you should employ `vector<pair<element_t, weight_t>>` for input data and `set<pair<weight_difference_t, index_t>>` as set of indices. All types are probably integers but I used custom types to show which data should be there. Your should also know how pair is compared.